# AWS cloud watch for live monitoring of applications

Tags: java, python, amazon-web-services, monitoring, amazon-cloudwatch

As per the documentation of [AWS Cloud watch](https://aws.amazon.com/cloudwatch/) it looks like Amazon's CloudWatch can help me in visualizing key metrics like CPU utilization and memory.

I am not sure if AWS cloud watch can be used for collecting more finer metrics published from application for its live monitoring.

For example:

1. Time Metric: Response time of a particular function in my application.
2. Count Metric: Number of times a function or part of a code is getting executed etc.

If AWS cloud can collect such metrics, can someone point me to the relevant documentation (architecture as well as setup) for doing so? If it cannot, please tell me an alternative way of collecting such metrics from an application (not necessarily in context of AWS, and it should be language agnostic meaning application written in any language should be able to emit such metrics to the metric collector agent).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Amazon CloudWatch supports publishing custom metrics from applications.
Below documentation describes the steps

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/monitoring/publishingMetrics.html

Hope this helps !!

Comment: Do you know of some open source project for the applications that are not hosted in AWS?